# Ubuntu 14.04: System Fonts garbled/invisible

Tags: 14.04, fonts

Irregularly, the fonts of my Ubuntu 14.04 system get garbled.

[image]

You can see here an excerpt of the erroneous fonts at 7:11 h and the same excerpt where the fonts are ok (at 7:20 h).

A reboot helps to solve this issue.

What could I do to analyze the problem?
What could I do to mitigate it (perhaps by choosing different fonts)?
What could I do to solve it completely?

Comment: I see you were using some transparency plugin. May I know which one of them and the customization in compiz? I suspect it's more of a graphics problem than font.

Comment: the transparency is just a side effect of the screen shotting.  I did not do any customization in compiz. The erroneous font / characters do appear also in other applications (like double commander, libre office)